# In Google Chrome, what is the extension api for changing the UserAgent and Device Metrics?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Google Chrome, when viewing the developer tools, in the bottom right there is a Gear Icon that opens an additional Settings popup. One of the pages in the Settings popup is Overrides that contains User Agent and Device Metrics settings. I am trying to find the extensions API that is able to set those values programatically. Does such an API exist?

I've looked the [main apis](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html), and the [experimental apis](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/experimental.html) , but can't seem to find anything.

The sample for devtools.panels in the [code samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html) doesn't seem to indicate how to 'explore' the existing devpanels either.

Specifically I'm trying to build simple extension available from a context menu in a Browser Action. It would act like a user-agent switcher, offering choices from the same list in the Settings popup, and automatically sets the Device Metrics to the values of the selected Agent. e.g. 640x960 for IPhone 4.

Any leads on how to programatically access the Settings popup

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some of the advanced features offered by the Developer tools can be accessed through the [`chrome.debugger`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger.html) API (add the `debugger` permission to the manifest file).

The User agent can be changed using the [`Network.setUserAgentOverride`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/tot/network#command-setUserAgentOverride) command:

```js
// Assume: tabId is the ID of the tab whose UA you want to change
// It can be obtained via several APIs, including but not limited to
// chrome.tabs, chrome.pageAction, chrome.browserAction, ...

// 1. Attach the debugger
var protocolVersion = '1.0';
chrome.debugger.attach({
    tabId: tabId
}, protocolVersion, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }
    // 2. Debugger attached, now prepare for modifying the UA
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
        tabId: tabId
    }, "Network.enable", {}, function(response) {
        // Possible response: response.id / response.error
        // 3. Change the User Agent string!
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
            tabId: tabId
        }, "Network.setUserAgentOverride", {
            userAgent: 'Whatever you want'
        }, function(response) {
            // Possible response: response.id / response.error
            // 4. Now detach the debugger (this restores the UA string).
            chrome.debugger.detach({tabId: tabId});
        });
    });
});
```

The official documentation for the supported protocols and commands can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol#protocol). As of writing, there's no documentation for changing the Device metrics. However, after digging in Chromium's source code, I discovered a file which defined all currently known commands:

- chromium/src/out/Debug/obj/gen/webcore/[InspectorBackendDispatcher.cpp](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=file:InspectorBackendDispatcher.cpp&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)

When I look through the list of definitions, I find `Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride`. This phrase seems to match our expectations, so let's search further, to find out how to use it:

- [Chromium code search: "Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride"](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)

This yields ["chromium/src/out/Release/obj/gen/devtools/DevTools.js"](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/out/Release/obj/gen/devtools/DevTools.js&q=Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride&sq=package:chromium&l=5150) (thousands of lines). Somewhere, there's a line defining (beautified):

```
InspectorBackend.registerCommand("Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride", [{
    "name": "width",
    "type": "number",
    "optional": false
}, {
    "name": "height",
    "type": "number",
    "optional": false
}, {
    "name": "fontScaleFactor",
    "type": "number",
    "optional": false
}, {
    "name": "fitWindow",
    "type": "boolean",
    "optional": false
}], []);
```

How to read this? Well, use your imagination:

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
    tabId: tabId
}, "Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride",{
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    fontScaleFactor: 1,
    fitWindow: false
}, function(response) {
    // ...
});
```

I've tested this in Chrome 25 using protocol version 1.0, and it works: The tab being debugged is resized. Yay!

Comment: Wow! This is one of the most complete, and thoughtful responses I've ever seen or had. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. However when I'm trying the soution I got "Error during debugger.attach: Another debugger is already attached to the tab with id" or "Error during debugger.sendCommand: Debugger is not attached to the tab with id: 43". Any similar issues with your code.

Comment: @KrasimirStefanovTsonev Currently, only one debugger instance can be attached (though the documentation hint that the ultimate desire is to allow multiple debuggers). You've probably opened developer tools (F12), an existing debugger, or a remote debugger to the tab you're debugging. Close the developer tools for the specific tab, and it will start to work.

Comment: Aha ... now I understand but what I want to do is to add this functionality in my extensions which is actually part of the dev tools :) So, I guess that it is not possible. When I skip the attaching part the first error with the "already attached ..." is gone, but the second one is still there. Is there any workaround for this situation. I.e. to use the code above, but to put it in a dev tools extension.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're out of luck *at the moment*.

Comment: Just to confirm that the code works when I use it in a browser action, which is kinda cool actually :)

Comment: do you know if it's possible to set the `Network.setUserAgentOverride` and the `Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride` objects in the same `chrome.debugger.sendCommand` call?

Comment: @pruett Not possible. But you can chain the callbacks to invoke the command twice before detaching the debugger.

Comment: I wonder if anybody tried to create a extension to create and fast switch device presets based on this api? Does something like this exist? It seems so obvious, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @PhilippMelab Want to collaborate on creating the extension? I've got the API implementation ready, I just need an options page plus some useful presets. My contact details are on my profile.

Comment: After a discussion with @PhilippMelab, it turns out that the extension is not needed for his use-case, because the feature already exists in the developer tools; see this Stack Overflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896883/true-mobile-screen-emulator/15905581#15905581.