# Permanently disable cache in incognito mode chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Every time I open a new incognito instance, I have to open the settings and click `Disable Cache` and `Enable Sourcemaps`.  This is pretty annoying and I would like have these settings saved permanently.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could create a Chrome extension which does it for you. Use the [`chrome.windows`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html), [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) and [`chrome.debugger`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15626197/938089) APIs. To save settings, you could use [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html).