# True mobile screen emulator ?

Tags: html, mobile, google-chrome-extension, viewport

I have this page :

http://people.opera.com/andreasb/viewport/ex01.html

Which uses viewport for different mobile screen sizes.

When I run this at my iphone I do see the font changes :

[image]

But when I use Ripple or other chrome extensions (which I found) , it doesnt show me the increased font size. only 
screen size is changing. ( but it doesnt affect the font size )

How can I emulate ( chrome extension) the screen size so it will show me as if I'm on real mobile ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a Chrome extension for that, the developer tools already have such a built-in feature.

1. Open the developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, ...).
2. Click on the gear in the bottom-right corner.
3. Click on "Overrides".
4. Enable "Device metrics", and adjust the "Screen resolution" / "Font scale factor" to your desired values.

Examples (360x200 and 200x360, I didn't zoom or resize the screenshots):

[image: 360x200]

[image: 200x360]

Some preset values can be used by switching the user agent (above "Device metrics"). If you want multiple custom values, create a Chrome extension using the [`chrome.debugger`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger.html) API.

Comment: Presets *are* available, you can choose an user agent which has a definite device size (e.g. iPhone - iOS 4)

Comment: @AlvinWong Thanks, didn't notice.

Comment: Rob , sorry for delay. I've just seen the answer. ( dont know how I didnt see it in the top left menu)

Comment: What do you do when the server respond conditionally of the type of device; Phone, tablet instead of just the screen resolution?

Comment: @Samuel Override the user agent string.