# Page.handleJavaScriptDialog does not work in Chrome 29

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using Page.handleJavaScriptDialog in chrome.debugger to handle js dialog in Chrome extension. 
But it fails in the latest Chrome 29.

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand({"tabId": 2}, "Page.handleJavaScriptDialog", {accept:true}, function(msg){});
```

Is there anything to replace or is this API changed?

Comment: Tried to use `Page.enable` before issuing the other command? Try the code structure of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15626197/938089

Comment: oh, sorry about forget to mention that i have use Page.enable and Runtime.enable before. @RobW