# How to access the DevTools API without actually opening the DevTools window?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) says "An instance of the extension's DevTools page is created each time a DevTools window opens. The DevTools page exists for the lifetime of the DevTools window."

However, the [Facebook Pixel Helper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/pixel-troubleshooting) manages to to get network information without the devtools window being open.

So, I was wondering if there was some other API or a workaround to access the content from the DevTools window (specifically the networks tab, which Facebook seems to be able to do).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `chrome.devtools` API cannot be used without opening the devtools window. The Facebook Pixel Helper uses the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API to get information about network requests. This API does not offer any access to the response body, so that's not particularly helpful.

There are some more (powerful) methods, which are *not* used by the [FB Pixel Helper extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fb-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc):

- The [`chrome.debugger`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API allows you to do almost anything that the devtools is capable of, including querying the response body, as long as the devtools window is not open. In the following explanation, I assume that you're already attached to the debugger. If you don't know how to do that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15626197) for an example.

  1. Add a listener to `chrome.debugger.onEvent`
  2. Send the `Network.enable` command to start listening to events.
  3. When a request completes, the `onEvent` event will be triggered, with the method name set to `Network.responseReceived`. The event parameters include things like the request/response headers, status line, etc. If you want to get the response body as well, invoke the `Network.getResponseBody` command to get the response body.

  For other network events/commands, see the [debugging protocol specification for network](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/network).
- [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) can use the [`performance.timing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming) API to query load times of the document in a (top-level/sub) frame.

Comment: where do I put the code for webRequests? In the content script or ..?

Comment: @praroh1 The background page. Content script do not have access to these APIs. You could use my [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) to view the source code of the Facebook Pixel Helper extension, if you need inspiration.

Comment: Ah! Perfect tool! Thanks for the tip man. You're a life saver.